# Culebra in AndroidViewClient returns "RuntimeError: ERROR: Connecting to <socket... [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: android, adb, androidviewclient

Trying to use any culebra (`AndroidViewClient`) command returns following error:

$culebra -G

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/culebra", line
>   4, in import('pkg_resources').run_script('androidviewclient==13.5.0',
>   'culebra') File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 739, in
>   run_script self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 1494,
>   in run_script exec(code, namespace, namespace) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-13.5.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/culebra",
>   line 1168, in device, serialno =
>   ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(serialno=serialno, **kwargs1) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-13.5.0-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py",
>   line 2697, in connectToDeviceOrExit device =
>   adbclient.AdbClient(serialno, ignoreversioncheck=ignoreversioncheck,
>   timeout=timeout) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-13.5.0-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py",
>   line 179, in init self.socket = AdbClient.connect(self.hostname,
>   self.port, self.timeout) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-13.5.0-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py",
>   line 252, in connect raise RuntimeError("ERROR: Connecting to %s:%d:
>   %s.\nIs adb running on your computer?" % (s, port, ex)) RuntimeError:
>   ERROR: Connecting to :5037: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Is adb
>   running on your computer?

Adb is debinitely running; "`adb devices`" lists connected device; "`adb push`", "`adb pull`","`adb shell`", all work fine.

Opening firewall, setting path, reinstalling AndroidViewClient, updating software make no difference.

A previous post "[androidviewclient - Can't connect to the device on vm with port forwarding][1]" concerns very similar error.

His solution (below) does not work for me:

> Blockquote

Solved - I changed localhost back to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file and it solves an issue...

> Blockquote

Any ideas?

[androidviewclient - Can't connect to the device on vm with port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526083/androidviewclient-cant-connect-to-the-device-on-vm-with-port-forwarding)

Comment: Are you using Linux? `adb` version? installed from?

Comment: `netstat -na`? is `adb` listening on port 5037?

Comment: Thanks for the comeback Diego, you're definitely the 
man I want to hear from about Culebra.

Using linux, MX16 (debian based), updated.
Adb  is Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31.
I assume adb came with Android Studio (android-studio-ide-171.4408382-linux).
Not sure though.

Output of 
netstat -na | grep 5037
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27563    /tmp/5037

Comment: If I kill the adb server and run adb devices, the daemon starts on 5037 and the phone is listed.

Comment: Let's recap. `adb` installed from Sdk, so `which adb` gives something like `/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`. Then, `adb devices` list your devices as `device` (online state), then you run `culebra -G` and connection fails even though you checked `netstat` and port 5037 is listening. Seems really strange. Are you sure you have only 1 `adb` installed on your system?

Comment: You nailed it, Diego! Second adb in /usr/bin. Removed it, culebra working great now. Thanks for the quick knowledgeable help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting default from JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.8 solved this problem.
Still getting an error message ("...there are no connected devices"), however since adb devices lists the phone, shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Marking this question solved

Comment: As Diego Torres Milano pointed out above the "...no connected devices" error message was from having 2 copies of adb installed.